# Odoo 10 unexpected delete all relation records after filter

Tags: odoo-10, delete-row, one2many

I'm in trouble when delete a record after filter.

I have record A loaded in form view (actually in my custom form view).
Record A have field B (one2many). When A's form view is loaded, B contains 3 records: B(1), B(2), B(3). Then by some way, I filter B list with some conditions. Now B list show 2 records: B(2), B(3).

If I click delete button of B(2), B list now have B(3). That's Ok.
Then I save A record, my B records has deleted all, while I experted that it still contains B(1) and B(2) in database.

I tried debug javascript to know what happends but without lucky.
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since problem occur when I custom form view, I has to edited some build-in javascript functions to solve it.

So if anyone have the same problem, then can try to debug **render_dataset** function in **ListView.Groups** class, in **web.ListView** javascript module, notice at **dataset** attribute of this class!